# Why is the passed variable not being accepted by the JS call?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

I've just Integrated **Stripe payment** with **Blogspot** website, so can only work with the front-end using HTML and JS.

When the user clicks the checkout button, the user's input is passed to the **Stripe Checkout** call, `stripes.redirectToCheckout()`, but the console throws up an **Error**:

[image: Zoomed In]

Here's the **Code**:

```
<input id="user-input">
<button>Checkout</button>

<script>

  checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
      var userInput = document.getElementById("user-input").value;
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({
        items: [{ quantity: userInput}],
        .
        . 
        .
  })

</script>
```

Screenshot:
[image: Console view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementById("user-input").value` returns a [string value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement), but `quantity` property needs a number, so you would need a [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).

```
items: [{ quantity: parseInt(userInput)}],
```